# how to called variables in the parent class

Tags: php

Hello guy i would like some help here

i had this class :

```
 class product 
        {
          var $title;
          var $price; 
          function __construct($title1,$price1)
          {

            $this->title=$title1;
            $this->price=$price1;
          }
          function set_title($newtitle){
            $this->title=$newtitle;
          }
          function get_title() {
            return $this->title;
          }
          function set_price($newprice)
          {
           return  $this->price=$newprice;

          }
          function getProductAtrribute ()
          {

             $x1=$this->title;
             $x2=$this->price;
             $x3=$this->**material**;
             $x4=$this->**size1**;
             return   $allattribute= array("$x1","$x2","x3","x4");
         }
        }
```

and other classs :

```
class furinture extends product
    {
      var $size;
      var $material;  

      function __construct($sizeset,$materialset)
      {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->size=$sizeset;
        $this->material=$materialset;
      }
    function  setsize ($size1,$material1)
    {
        $this->size=$size1;
        $this->material=$material1;
    }
```

what i am trying to do i set the value of the size and material in the class furniture but get from the function get all attribute in the class product i tried to make global variable but it wont work .
 note : the $size  and $ material i want them to define the furniture class like its define

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable

Comment: this how to access parent class i need to access child class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774612/access-child-class-static-variables-from-parent-class

Answer (score 0):

Amend your product class like this,

```
    class product 
    {
      private $title;
      private $price; 
      private $size;
      private $material;  

      public function setup_product($title1,$price1)
      {
        $this->title=$title1;
        $this->price=$price1;
      }

      public function set_title($newtitle){
        $this->title=$newtitle;
      }

      public function set_material($material){
        $this->material=$material;
      }

      public function set_size($size){
        $this->size=$size;
      }

      public function get_title() {
        return $this->title;
      }

      public function get_price() {
        return $this->price;
      }

      public function set_price($newprice)
      {
       return  $this->price=$newprice;

      }

      public function getProductAtrribute()
      {

         $x1=$this->title;
         $x2=$this->price;
         $x3=$this->material;
         $x4=$this->size;
         return $allattribute= array("$x1","$x2","x3","x4");
     }
    }
```

Amend Furniture Class;

```
class furinture extends product
{
  public function __construct($sizeset,$materialset,$title1,$price1)
  {
    $this->setup_product($title1,$price1)
    $this->size=$sizeset;
    $this->material=$materialset;
  }
  public function setsize($size1,$material1)
  {
    $this->set_size($size1);
    $this->set_material($material1);
  }

 }
```

Comment: i don't want to get price from the child class , i want to get the size and material from the parent class product in the function  getallattribute () .as you see i get x3 , and x 4 one for matrieal and other for the size

Comment: I have extended the furniture class above now to return the `allAttributes() function`

Comment: i agree with you but still not helpful . please read function getallattribute . x3 , and x4 .

Comment: Amended again. If this does not solve the issue, please could you explain exactly what you are trying to do in a little more detail?

Comment: i am trying to do : 1. Catalog contains two product types ​furniture and CD/DVD disks 2. All product types have two attributes in common ​title and price. 3. Additional attributes for furniture:
a. Size (string like 200x200x100)
b. Material (wood or plastic) 4. Additional attributes for CD/DVD:
a. Size in MB (integer value like 700)
b. Manufacturer. .....  
In product class please provide following functions (it’s up to You to choose function names): 1. Function to get product name 2. Function to get product attribute
3. Function to get all product attributes Size attribute for CD/DVD

Comment: but i am going step by step so so far i need to do furniture class :) , which is get title and price form from the product which is for all other classes but i need one function exactly in the product class will return me all attribute for all classes . for now is just the furniture class

Comment: i do not want material and size in the product class i need it to be in the furniture class , but when i got it i need to get from the function called get all product attribute which in the parent "product class" .

Answer (score -1):

Use public, private or protected for your atributes instead of var.
then you can acces it from `$this->price;` etc...

or you could do accesor an call it with parent::yourMethod();

Comment: but i would like to access is the size and material in the child class , but get it in the , class product as you see in code , and in function getallattribute ,i tried public material , public size , its not working

Comment: Using `var` puts the scope to `public` anyway

Comment: you could try to use abstract class